# Where does cURL store data while it's still downloading?

Tags: curl

I'm using cURL on the command line to automate the downloading of many files from a server. I'm wondering where cURL stores its data whilst it's downloading.

The reason I need this info is so I can calculate the amount of data which has been downloaded as a percentage of the total.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-#` switch to display the progress bar.

[image: Screenshot of cURL progress bar in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

While downloading, `curl` buffers data in the RAM and regularly flushes it to the output (which is probably a file in your case, but may be anything).

Looking at its manual page, I don't see an easy way to get download progress within a script. If you'd provide more details, I'll try to find a solution.